# Is this possible to send tweet from application to user wall?

Tags: php, twitter

I have registered an application in Twitter. Now I want to send every update to user from application in the form of tweets using php :

```
$consumer_key       = 'XXXXX';
$consumer_secret    = 'XXXXX';
$oauth_token        = 'XXXXX';
$oauth_secret       = 'XXXXX';
$connection = new TwitterOAuth($consumer_key, $consumer_secret, $oauth_token, $oauth_secret);
$connection->host = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/";
$connection->ssl_verifypeer = TRUE;
$parameters = array('status'=>'this is a message');
$status = $connection->post('statuses/update',$parameters);
```

The code is working fine but it is posting tweet **from** user's own account to his wall which is not what I want. I want to send tweet **from application** to user's wall.

Comment: Add user's twitter handle(eg @twitteraccount) in your tweet content. and tweet will sent to user.

Comment: @Ravi Re-read the question at the bottom.

Comment: I got the question correctly. He can use this api code to get authenticated user's twitter handle  and send a tweet using application's twitter handle to user's twitter handle.

Comment: @Ravi can you please provide a code